# Database Creation/Management Strategy : CoreData or File

Tags: database, file, swift, core-data, ios8

I need to import data (a list of sprite properties) into an iOS8 application written in Swift. The data consists in one excel type file of 20 columns and around 10000 lines (so one table with 20 fields and 10000 records in database terms, fields can be num, string or boolean). Some lines (most of them) won't have value for each column. This import has to be done very regularly during the development phase to update (replace all in fact) the data.

I won't need to do any change on this set of data in the app and I need to avoid to have this import triggered by the user. I'll just need to select small chunks of it (1 to 100) and load them in an array of dictionaries where keys will be column labels. But I need to be able to access the full set of data anytime (not just a chunk when the app launch and nothing else after).

The data can't be hard coded and managed directly into Xcode because they are generated by a relational database that creates the flat file I need to import.

I'm wondering what is the best strategy to do this (as I'm new to Swift and iOS I'd like to learn directly the best way to do it) :

- Should I use Core Data and load everything into one entity, then fetch my subset of data when I need it ?
- Should I use a text file (or any other format) that I include somewhere and read from it when I need ?
- Or is there another smart and beautiful option ?

Comment: Take a look at NSAtomicStore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying several options, a mix of CoreData + csv files is the best answer to this kind of simple database management in my case.

- I manage my data in a relational database (4D in my case)
- I have replicated my relational database structure into CoreData
- I export each file in a CSV format and load them into CoreData with the help of this SwiftCSV tool (https://github.com/naoty/SwiftCSV)